# How to fill the Values of a Map Object with an Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an object and an array. Both the array and the object are 24 pairs/index long. How do I substitute the values of the object with the values of the array?
This does not work:

```
for (let keys of zeitFaktor.keys() ){
    for (ix = 0; ix < 24; ix++){
        zeitFaktor.set(keys, patientenFaktoren[ix]);
    };
};
```

Here all of the keys are paired with the first value of the array. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you reformat your question into what your `input` is and what you want for your `output` along with the code (cleaned up)

Comment: please add the missing parts as well, like `zeitFaktor` and `patientenFaktoren`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only need one loop, not a nested one. Go for a loop mechanism that also gives you the index of the key:

```
Array.from(zeitFaktor.keys(), (key, ix) =>
    zeitFaktor.set(key, patientenFaktoren[ix])
);
```

```js
const zeitFaktor = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['d', 1]]);
const patientenFaktoren = [15, 37, -23, 6];

Array.from(zeitFaktor.keys(), (key, ix) =>
    zeitFaktor.set(key, patientenFaktoren[ix])
);

console.log([...zeitFaktor]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

`zeitFaktor.keys()` returns an iterator, which `Array.from` "consumes". While `Array.from` pulls every key from that iterator, it passes it to the callback function. That callback function will get both the key and the index order in which it occurs.

The callback function is written as an arrow function (`=>`), using the short expression syntax (no braces). This means that `zeitFaktor.set(key, patientenFaktoren[ix])` is evaluated for each key, and this will modify the Map as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I don't understand 100 percent how this works, it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I added a bit of explanation. Let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: Yes it helped a lot. Array.from was new to me but I understand it know. The arrow function you wrote is actually the mapping function argument of Array.from and sets the rules how Array.from modifies the map. What was irritating is that the ?method? Array.from has the word "Array" in it but zeitFaktor still stays a map after the code is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure `zeitFaktor` contains the same number of elements as `patientenFaktoren`, you can simply use its keys in a single-loop and iteration:

```
const keys = zeitFaktor.keys();

for (let ix = 0; ix < 24; ix++) {
  const key = keys.next().value;
  zeitFaktor.set(key, patientenFaktoren[ix]);
}
```